# Brezis Exercise 3.13 item 3.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology, strong-convergence

I work in the following question:

> Let $E$ be a space Banach, $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset E$, $x \in E$ and \begin{equation*}
>    K_{n}= \overline{con(\bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty}\{xi\})}.
>   \end{equation*}
> prove: If $E$ is finite dimensional and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_{n} = \{ x \}$, then $x_{n} \to x$.

The prove:
We may asume that $x = 0$. consider the recesion cone
\begin{equation*}
   C_{n} = \bigcap_{\lambda > 0}\lambda K_{n} 
  \end{equation*}
Since $C_{n}\subset K_{n}$ we deduce that  $ \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}C_{n} =  \{0\} $. Let $S= \{ x \in E: \|x\| = 1 \}$ the sequence $C_{n}\cap S$ is decrecent and  $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(C_{n}\cap S) = \emptyset $. Thus, by compactness $C_{n_{0}}\cap S = \emptyset$ for some $ n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} $. therefore  $C_{n_{0}} = \{ 0 \}$ and consequently $K_{n_{0}}$  is bounded. Hence $(x_{n})$ is bounded. (So we are  in the conditions previous item of this same exercise and it´s just conclude )

But. i don´t understand why  $C_{n_{0}} = \{ 0 \}$? And why $C_{n_{0}} = \{ 0 \}$ implies $K_{n_{0}}$ is bounded?

(There is another way to solve the problem:  suppose that $\{x_{n}\}$ is unbounded but i couldn´t do it this way.)

thanks.

Comment: If there exist $x_0\in C_{n_0}$ and $x_0\ne 0$, then $x_0\in \lambda K_{n_0},\,\forall \lambda>0$. Hence, $\frac{x_0}{\lambda}\in K_{n_0},\forall \lambda >0$ and $\eta x_0\in C_{n_0},\forall \eta>0$. In particular, $\frac{x_0}{\lVert x_0\rVert}\in C_{n_0}\cap S$. It is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.xue. If I have that $\frac{x_{0}}{\lambda}$ for any $\lambda > 0$. I can´t conclude from there what in particular for $\lambda = \frac{1}{\|x\|}$?

Comment: Note that $K_{n_0}$ is closed and convex. We have assume that $0\in K_{n_0}$. Therefore, if $\frac{x_0}{\lambda}\in K_{n_0}$ , then $\frac{x_0}{\lambda}\in \eta K_{n_0}$ for all $\eta>0$ by convexity. It conclude that $\frac{x_0}{\lVert x_0\rVert}\in C_{n_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $K_{n_0}$ is unbound, then $\forall n>0,\, \exists \lVert x_n\rVert>n,$ s.t. $$\frac{x_n}{\lVert x_n\rVert}\in(\cap_{\lambda\ge \frac{1}{m}}\lambda K_{n_0})\cap S,\, \forall m\le n.$$ Denote $y_n=\frac{x_n}{\lVert x_n\rVert}$. $\{y_n\}$ is bounded and $S$ is compact, therefore there exists y such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=y$ . Because $(\cap_{\lambda\ge \frac{1}{n}}\lambda K_n)\cap S$ is compact, $y\in (\cap_{\lambda\ge \frac{1}{n}}\lambda K_{n_0})\cap S,\forall n$. Hence, $y\in (C_{n_0})\cap S = \emptyset$.

Comment: thanks @Mr.xue. Can you please explain to me why $\frac{x_n}{\lVert x_n\rVert}\in(\cap_{\lambda\ge \frac{1}{m}}\lambda K_{n_0})\cap S,\, \forall m\le n.$? Thanks again.

Comment: @Gema89. Since $x_n\in K_{n_0}$ and $0\in K_{n_0}$, we can obtain $\lambda x_n \in \lambda K_{n_0}$ and $0\in K_{n_0}$. Since $\rVert\lambda x_n\rVert\ge \frac{1}{n} \lVert x_n\rVert \ge 1$, we conclude that $\frac{x_n}{\lVert x_n\rVert}\in \lambda K_{n_0}$.

Comment: thanks. understand.